# How to recover unsaved modifications of a saved Microsoft word 2010 file?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I modified an already saved word file and suddenly power was cut and my computer got switched off. When I turned the computer on again and opened the word document the file with the latest modifications had not been recovered. I tried all the ways I could to recover it but I couldn't. Please please help me recover it. Thanks a lot. This is my final hope.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This site is geared toward helping with specific problems when you attempt something and get stuck. It is not a recovery service. I will say this; depending how you have Word configured, there may be a little hope. There are tons of resources on the Internet on how to recover lost files. Like this - [How to recover a lost Word document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316951/how-to-recover-a-lost-word-document). After you try something, update your question with specifics and we can try to help.

Comment: Okay, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Once you open that file left side corner it will ask you the last modified data in this file. You have to choose that and apply.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is great that you are jumping in to help. Couple pointers for you about answering questions. We are looking for detailed answers rather than a couple simple sentences. Reading thru [answer] will help you understand what the site expects in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is it:

Go to File -> Info -> Manage Versions.

Then click on the drop-down and select "Recover Unsaved Documents".

[image]

Microsoft Word will open the location where a copy of the draft resides.

Now, it’s just a matter of selecting the draft!

Comment: Your image link is bad. Also, Manage Versions only works on open files. The OP has stated that the file was unsaved and force closed. The only hope may be if AutoSave is turned on.

Comment: Mr.kevin I really appreciate your helping me but this was already tried and  well​, I didn't get my file. I think I have to start over again. Anyway thanks for your efforts.